# Is SQL Server Security Policy executed per row or per select

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-level-security, security-policy

Lets say I have

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [sec].[PartyGroupAccessPredicate](@PartyGroupId uniqueidentifier)
    RETURNS TABLE     
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS accessResult
        FROM [sec].[PartyGroupPartyLink] partyGroupLink
        WHERE
        (
            partyGroupLink.PartyGroupId = @PartyGroupId AND partyGroupLink.PartyId = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'PartyId') AS VARCHAR(50))
            AND @PartyGroupId IS NOT NULL
        )
        
GO



CREATE SECURITY POLICY [sec].[PartyGroupAccessPolicy] 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [sec].[PartyGroupAccessPredicate]([PartyGroupId]) ON [int].[Program]
```

... would the security policy execute for each row or does sql do some optimization where its executed only once?

Is there any better approaches that would be more performant?

Comment: If I had to bet, I would think it executes once per row. If so, memory optimized tables might help, if that were available to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827994/sql-server-2016-with-row-level-security-addressing-the-bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

The security policy is applied at row level. This is how row level security is being implemented in SQL Server.
Reference: [Row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Row%2DLevel%20Security%20enables%20you,restrictions%20on%20data%20row%20access.)
Regarding, your query on performant, If you need to apply multiple filters, then it will have an impact.